# How to set the ylabel horizontal in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

how to set the ylabel horizontal in gnuplot, like this,
[right ylabel style I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv8rs.png).
While I use

> set ylabel "Episode Duration (seconds)"

and

> set ylabel "Episode Duration (seconds)" rotate by 90

the picture I get are like this
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVfcd.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The angle for a horizontal label is 0°. This should work:

```
set lmargin 15
set ylabel "Episode\n Duration\n (seconds)" offset 2,1 rotate by 0
plot sin(x)
```

Note that I had to increase the left margin so that the ylabel fits on the picture. And I have shifted the label.

[image]

Comment: Yes, works perfect, Thank you! I thought the rotate is to rotate how much degree.

Comment: That's correct, you have to specify the rotation angle. It is an **absolute** angle measured relative to horizontal orientation. The default rotation angle for the ylabel is already 90 degrees, so it does not change if it is set again to 90 degrees, the values are not additive.